# Unpacking NSArrays into String swift

Tags: json, swift, firebase-realtime-database, nsarray

I want to unpack an array of users to a single string.

For instance in my app there are group chats and each time a user enters a group chat their uid is added to a list of members. I want to return all members in a single group chat as a string in app.

Each room is represented in code as the following data object

```
class Room: NSObject {

    var owner: String?
    var groupChatName: String?
    var groupChatDescription: String?
    var members: [NSArray]?

}
```

Below is where I retrieve each room from the database.

```
func fetchAllRooms(){
    Database.database().reference().child("rooms").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let room = Room()
            room.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

            self.rooms.append(room)
            print(snapshot)

            print(room.members?.joined())
            print(self.rooms.count)

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            })
        }

        print("end of snap")

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

`print(room.members?.joined())` Is what currently crashes the app and throws 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:

> '-[__NSDictionaryI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800146ab80'

I realize it could possibly be how my data is structured so here's a look at the json

```
"A632CA68-40D9-4F3A-B8C8-245457057443" : {
  "groupChatDescription" : "Test Description",
  "groupChatName" : "Test Name",
  "members" : {
    "WuqCAt4mM3h0P0X1m7hVZ7NQyLC2" : {
      "username" : "Steve"
    }
  },
  "owner" : "Steve"
},
```

Any answers, suggestions, and or references are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are setting dictionary on your class. So first you need to extract the value from dictionary and set it to your Room model class properties. After that try invoke joined method on your array then it should work.

Comment: Is it possible to add a value to the dictionary after the values are downloaded. I know that usually if they don't match up the app will crash.

Comment: So from the dictionary you can access the value from its key. So set that value inside your Model class properties. Is that make sense?